# Codes shown on GitHub differs from what really are

Tags: github

The code appearing on my GitHub is not exactly the some as the one which I've written and can be downloaded.

Here exactly what I mean:

the link to my repository is

https://github.com/stefanovic80/PythonMap/blob/master/Python_Map_ipyleaflet.ipynb

which is a jupyter notebook code. The issue comes into the first cell, which on GitHub appears like this

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(""))
display(HTML(""))
display(HTML(""))
```

but this is not what I've written, not what I was able to read few days before, not even what I get on my local machine once I've cloned it!

Hence, something happenend recently, but I don know what!

In fact, once cloned, on my machine I can have the right lines of code which are

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.output_result { max-width:100% !important; }</style>"))
display(HTML("<style>.prompt { display:none !important; }</style>"))
```

What's happening?

I would like to have the opportunity to copy and paste the code directly from my GitHub whenever I need it, without passing through a cloning procedure. Could you suggest me anything, please?

Comment: GitHub's notebook rendering isn't perfect and is best considered as a preview for simple things. Up until the last few years most users learned quickly that what GitHub provides was just a basic preview for the simplest notebooks **because it wouldn't even attempt to render anything more than a few cells long.** Sadly, with some improvements to the rendering, the overall pitfalls aren't learned fast by novices.  I see something much different if you go to https://nbviewer.org/ & view your notebook. (The pattern of the URL for the nbviewer renderings is actually a variation on the GitHub URL.)

Comment: Your notebooks renders that first cell nicely at https://nbviewer.org/github/stefanovic80/PythonMap/blob/master/Python_Map_ipyleaflet.ipynb . And matches the [raw code here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefanovic80/PythonMap/master/Python_Map_ipyleaflet.ipynb). Please use [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/) for viewing and sharing notebooks. It is provided by the Jupyter community for this purpose and overcomes a lot of shortcomings of the GitHub preview. Also the nbviewer rendering doesn't have a lot of the GitHub 'stuff' around it, which makes it nicer for sharing with non-developers.

Comment: For completeness sake, nbviewer does much better in the categories of allow keeping interactive Plotly plots still interactive (see my comment below OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71342892/python-plotly-chart-rendered-as-png-in-jupyter-notebook#comment126105113_71342892)), scrolling of code cells to the right works while GitHub at present cuts off, adding vertical scrollbars, animations with frames generated previously remain interactive on nbviewer and not on GitHub, nbviewer justifies the text in MultiIndex Pandas dataframes better, etc. (No room to link to examples for all.)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you already copy and pasted, forgot about it, and then you went back to get the code again, but it wasn't there since you copy and pasted.

I would suggest doing a clone every time if you are editing.

Comment: Something changed in the way GitHub shows codes, at least in the ways it shows jupyter notebook codes. Because, once cloned, it does not miss anything and it's exactly what I mean. I have the some issue in several different repositories. I can not believe I did anything like a copy and paste by mistake

Comment: You didn't, @Stefano. You can clearly see your code for the first cell by pressing the 'Raw' button on the page at the link you provided in your post. The first `display(HTML...` line is very different at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefanovic80/PythonMap/master/Python_Map_ipyleaflet.ipynb , which is the display of the raw underlying json code. That first line reads `"display(HTML(\"<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>\"))\n"` in the json of your notebook. You are just stumbling into one of the many deficiencies of the GitHub **preview**, see my comments below your post.